# Confusing error in apache

Tags: apache

I am trying to resolve an error that my apache is returning:

```
[Thu May 02 20:59:40 2013] [notice] child pid 10542 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu May 02 20:59:41 2013] [notice] child pid 10541 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu May 02 20:59:41 2013] [notice] child pid 10543 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu May 02 20:59:41 2013] [notice] child pid 10544 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu May 02 20:59:41 2013] [notice] child pid 10545 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu May 02 20:59:41 2013] [notice] child pid 10547 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

When this error happens, the page is aborted and does not return any message.

All this happens when I check for a session variable on my page:

```
if (! isset ($ _SESSION ['cartId'])) {}
```

I found some solutions on the internet but nothing worked.

Comment: There is more to it than this.  What you have isn't a reproducible example.  The problem you are having is usually caused by a bug in PHP.  Try to narrow things down to the actual problem.  I doubt that simply doing an `isset()` is causing this... unless you compiled from the latest source.

Comment: Your spacing is weird. `$ _SESSION [` especially looks wrong.  `if (! isset($_SESSION['cartId'])) {}` would be better.

Comment: I get this: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_SESSION' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'`. Whatever, "Segmentation fault" is a standard error message—it means "your program crashed".

Answer (score 0):

```
if (! isset ($ _SESSION ['cartId'])) {}
```

try

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cartId'])) {}
```

Comment: The syntax in my program is correct. Importantly, the error occurs only when the $ _SESSION ['cartId'] does not exist. If I assign a value in another file, the program runs normally.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in my program is correct. Importantly, the error occurs only when the $ _SESSION ['cartId'] does not exist. If I assign a value in another file, the program runs normally